# Return statement while using worker thread

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, worker-thread

Do I always have to return something using Worker Thread in Swing? What if I don't have any return value? I just want to use the worker thread to run an infinite for loop... so what to return? and even if I write a dummy return statement after the infinite for loop, say for e.g return 0; then also it will probably say "code not reachable".

Comment: Please show some code - after trying it...

Comment: what is there to try here? It's just that I do not want to return any value. but the construct method for worker thread is `public Object construct()`, which means that it needs a return value. i want to use this piece of code in the worker thread.
for(;;){
  Node.execution();
  Clock.incrementTimeTick();
  System.out.println(Clock.getTimeInTick());
  repaint();
}

Comment: Well for a start, you've written that "it will probably say..." - which means you haven't tried it. And I suspect you haven't tried it *without* a return statement, either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you haven't tried it. The code you've suggested in the comment should work fine:

```
public Object construct() {
  for (;;) {
    Node.execution();
    Clock.incrementTimeTick();
    System.out.println(Clock.getTimeInTick());
    repaint();
  }
  // End of loop is unreachable, so no need for a return statement.
}
```

A tight loop like this seems like a bad idea to me, and the `repaint()` code will need to be made appropriately thread-safe, but it should compile...

Personally I prefer to use `while (true)` for "forever" loops, but `for (;;)` should work too.

Comment: Skeet I haven't tried it because before this, whenever I have written code after an infinite loop, it always said "unreachable code". and moreover I am asking for suggestion. let's say you guys say that it's not a good idea to implement infinite loops using worker threads, then I'll probably ask for what to use.well sorry for not trying but I'm actually asking for a suggestion on how to implement this infinite thread, rather than being hellbent on using worker threads.

Comment: "A tight loop like this seems like a bad idea to me"... any better way?

Comment: @aps: It's always a good idea to try *before* you ask for help - particularly if it's only a matter of a compiler error that you're afraid of. But usually tight loops are a bad idea because they'll tie up the processor forever... we can't really tell you a "better way" because we don't know what you're trying to achieve. You've stated that you want an infinite loop, and you've given an example of one which looks like it's a *tight* loop (no waiting). You haven't said anything about the bigger picture.

Comment: well I'm sorry but it was not just the compiler error, but implementing this infinite loop in a thread-safe, good way. well the bigger picture is : I'm programming a simulator. Now I get various settings from the user via the GUI, then when the start button is clicked, the simulation starts. Node.execution() is a call to the Node class, which does various calculations which runs the simulation.After the whole scene is run once, i increment the time by one. this time is my own time, no relation with real time.then i repaint() to see it visually. this continues forever.

Comment: any ideas on making the loop better would really help.

Comment: @aps: Well for one thing, you'll almost certainly want a way of indicating that you've stopped. Some sort of rate limiter (a sleep!) would also probably be appropriate.

Comment: Maybe a Thread.sleep for a couple of milliseconds after every one execution of the loop? and yes a stop button. or a pause button.

Comment: @aps: A sleep like that *may* be appropriate, yes. Bear in mind the threading model of Swing though - you'll need to get the repaint to occur on the UI thread. As for a pause or stop button - that just needs to set a flag (in a thread-safe fashion) which the loop takes note of.

Comment: ok. btw, I tried the loop in eclipse. I don't know why it isn't working as you said it would.
        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
            public Object construct() {
           Node.execution();
           Clock.incrementTimeTick();
           System.out.println(Clock.getTimeInTick());
           repaint();
            }
         };
         worker.start();
the error is:
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 This method must return a result of type Object

 at gui.MyJFrame$1.construct(MyJFrame.java:52)
 at gui.SwingWorker$2.run...

Comment: you know I should bang my head against a wall with Java engraved on it.I knew I must have made some mistake again.please don't mind.

Comment: As far as I know, repaint() is a thread-safe method and does not need to be called on the Swing event thread.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the worker as `SwingWorker<Void, SomeObject>` and just return `null`. Trick the compiler about the infinite loop. Make it depending on some method that in the runtime always return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

A method like the follow will compile without any compilation errors:

```
public Object foo() {
    for (;;) {
        // do something ... or nothing
    }
}
```

The reason is that any statement following the `for` loop is unreachable, according to the rules set out in the [JLS 14.21](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.21).  Specifically

1. Any `for` loop with no condition expression (or a condition expression that is a compile-time constant expression with value `true`) cannot "complete normally".
2. Any statement in a block that is preceded by a statement which cannot complete normally is unreachable.